# django-haystack and endless pagination can't {% include page_template %}

Tags: django-haystack, django-endless-pagination

```
@page_template('voziladijelovi_dodatak.html')
def traziVozilaDijelovi(request):
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(kategorije=('Vozila i Dijelovi')).facet('podkategorije').facet('drzava').facet('grad')
    view = FacetedSearchView(form_class=FacetedSearchForm, searchqueryset=sqs)

    return view(request)
```

in template {% include page_template %} doesn't work.

extra_context   {u'page_template': u'voziladijelovi_dodatak.html'} is missing from
create_response()

How to include this in view

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like:

```
view = FacetedSearchView(form_class=FacetedSearchForm, 
            searchqueryset=sqs, 
            template='voziladijelovi_dodatak.html')
```